# Optimization, abstract classes and interfaces

Tags: c#, class, methods, interface, abstract

A bit of a broad question, but I have always wondered what the difference is in runtime optimization between an abstract class vs an interface.

When you are in a situation when you could use them interchangeably, and the two are roughly the same code density: Whats faster? and does it even matter ??

and if you could give specific numeric comparison, my mind would be blow :)

Comment: In almost all cases, it doesn't matter, and efficiency shouldn't be the governing factor behind the decision until you've *proved* it makes a difference in your case.

Comment: you might be interested in these resources, as I would be very suspicious about a situation where you could just use them `interchangeably`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d(v=vs.71).aspx  and  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ad621b8-a915-4d7e-89c3-5dbbc47202fd/whats-the-difference-between-abstract-classes-and-interfaces

Comment: FYI, the times I have been able to use then interchangeably have been specifically when making object bundles (IE: a list with a specific purpose) .....  For most cases I stand by using the most *expandable* option for your situation above all else

Comment: When using this pattern to make 'object bundles' (i guess you mean instances of different classes put into one list), I would keep in mind, that a class can only have one base class, but implement several interfaces. So for this purpose, i would go with an interface. Letting those classes derive from a base class just to group them together in a list seems inappropriate to me.
but, as almighty @JonSkeet said - performance wise, it will most likely not matter. You should analyze for different key factors first (which will certainly almost always be there).

Comment: @chips_100 In most of my cases, the objects exist only inside bundles (these are AI behavior bundles, or GUI bundles, stuff that only is useful in the bundle).... Personally I went the way of a abstract class so I didn't need to rewrite all the variables (even though most of the time there where only 2)

Comment: So it's seems like the response is (it does not matter)

Comment: "When you are in a situation when you could use them interchangeably"  But you won't be, because they are completely different concepts and there *aren't* situations in which either one would appropriate represent what's going on.

Comment: Well, in my experience there have been a number of times that both could be used to the same effect~  But after some thought I have being following the philosophy of ....."If you might need add more types, use interfaces, if you don't need to rewrite methods, use a class"